# Alternative promise due to ES6 Promise not being defined

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, phonegap

```
var all = promises.reduce(function (cur, next) {
     return cur.then(next);
}, Promise.resolve(true));
```

I have a phonegap app that is working fine except on an android tablet with android 4.4...this doesn't support ES6 Promise statement above.  Can anyone help in changing the above statement to use $q promise library instead?

Answer (score 1):

```
var all = promises.reduce(function (cur, next) {
    return cur.then(next);
}, $q.resolve(true));
```

Comment: **Note:** ES6 promises should be avoided in AngularJS applications as they are not integrated with the AngularJS framework and its digest cycle. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc. Use `$q.resolve` to bring ES6 promises and promises from other libraries into the AngularJS context.